# AngularJS. Directive for adding row with inputs in my form not work, because rows has same model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have directive, that adding row of inputs in my form. This row have dropdown. If I selecting value from one of dropdown, other also selecting with this value. This is my directive:

```
app.directive("addRow", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log("test")
      element.bind("click", function() {
        var row = angular.element("<div></div>");
        var html = '<div class="col-sm-1"><select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item for item in list" class="form-control"></select></div>';
        row.html(html);
        $compile(row)($scope);
        $(this).before(row);  
      });

    }
  }
})
```

And litter plunker to show the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/3rDB7JmKMgzPjYHWASf9?p=preview

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Not the answer of your question but : Any reason for not using the "Angular way" of doing things ?
Most of the time you won't need DOM manipulation or jQuery usage.
For your specific example, consider trying ngRepeat : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: @Neozaru thanks for comment! I've done this thing with ng-repeat and add() method, which just adds new row to scope. Fixed!